# Include number of observations for each variable pair when exporting estpost corr to .rtf using esttab

Tags: stata

I am trying to create a correlation matrix in Stata that a) includes the number of observations for each row and b) can be exported to a .docx or .rtf file. I am currently using `estout`, specifically the `estpost corr` option. My problem is that `estpost corr` reports the `e(count)` number in the last column, but using `esttab` with the `unstack` option makes the `e(count)` disappear. Since `estpost corr` returns `e(count)` as vector, there should be a way to add these, but I am not sure how. I want the correlations to be formatted like `unstack` does. I just want one new column with the number of observations after the variable names / labels. I am using Stata 18 on a Windows computer.

```
input id trial1 trial2 trial3
1 1.5 1.4 1.6 
2 1.5 . 1.9 
3 . 2.0 1.6 
4 . . 2.2 
5 1.9 2.1 2
6 1.8 2.0 1.9
7 . .  .
end

estpost corr trial1 trial2 trial3, matrix
esttab using correlations.rtf, replace unstack
```